# Installing Symfony2 in a web server

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to install Symfony2 in a web server, but I have one question about URL's.

I want to install it in this url.

```
http://mywebsite.com/gestor
```

So, is possible to put the files allocated in the /web folder into this directory (gestor), and put the others (/app, /bin, /src…) in another path in the server (an make them private, and impossible to access through URL?

Which is the best way? Just do it and modify the app.php requires?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you out, but I'm not really an expert on this topic? are you installing on a shared or dedicated hosting?

If you are on a dedicated hosting, you could go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424728/rewriterule-in-apache-with-symfony2-not-removing-app-php).

But I'm assuming you are installing on a shared hosting(courtesy of KBrogan):
 could anyone point me to how to mod_rewrite www.site.com/appname/web/app.php to a more sexy url of www.site.com which will automatically redirect to www.site.com/appname... without checking the url to the long version?

```
<bernardnapoleon> i've been googling for hours now. >><
<helios_ag> r u  on shared hosting?
<bernardnapoleon> yes
<KBrogan> bernard, i have just the solution for you if you would like everything redirected to site.com/index.php with your content stored in webroot/Symfony
<bernardnapoleon> really? you're amazing!
<bernardnapoleon> that's it
<KBrogan> 1) move Symfony/web to webroot/
<bernardnapoleon> okay but wouldn't that break the folder structure of symfony?
<KBrogan> nope
<KBrogan> 2) change the require_once tags in both files webroot/app(_dev)?.php to point to Symfony/app/... instead of pointing to ../Symfony/app
<KBrogan> example: require_once __DIR__.'/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php';
<bernardnapoleon> oks! done
<KBrogan> make .htaccess in webroot this:
<KBrogan> RedirectMatch 404 "^/Symfony(/.*)?$"
<KBrogan> RedirectMatch 404 "/\..*"
<KBrogan> RedirectMatch 404 "/(config||app(_dev)?).php"
<KBrogan> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<KBrogan>     RewriteEngine On
<KBrogan>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
<KBrogan>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
<KBrogan> </IfModule>
<KBrogan> last step - make a symlink index.php => app_dev.php
<bernardnapoleon> ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh...................
<KBrogan> Do you have shell access on your host bernard?
<bernardnapoleon> nope
<helios_ag> not good idea to publish dev env on prod env
<bernardnapoleon> helios_ag: yep yep. 
<KBrogan> dev env ip blacklists itself. Not really an issue until you've deployed
<bernardnapoleon> KBrogan: Thank you! 
<bernardnapoleon> i'll just rename app.php to index.php incase i can't do symlink
<KBrogan> if you don' t have shell access: either make a link with php, or rename the app.php
<bernardnapoleon> yeah. Thanks Again Bro
<bernardnapoleon> =)
<bernardnapoleon> all this time I thought the answer is in mod_rewrite
<KBrogan> i'm quite happy with the results there. Spent a couple of hours tweaking it
<KBrogan> I've got shell access, so I set up an alias dev and an alias prod which switches the environment for me and clears the cache
<KBrogan> Question: is there a twif filter which pretty prints all your html?
<KBrogan> twig*
<bernardnapoleon> oh cool. 
<bernardnapoleon> not an expert but I think you have to post process that. 
<KBrogan> by the way bernard, the RedirectMatch 404 "/\..*" bit will hide all of your .htaccess files and make them return 404 instead of 403
<KBrogan> as well as any other file that stats with .
<KBrogan> and any other file besides /Symfony/* , index.php, app_dev.php, app.php, will be served directly by Apache
<bernardnapoleon> ohhhh
```