# Silex Routing Issues (other paths besides root giving 404)

Tags: php, silex

This seems like it should work but I get a 404 error.

My app looks like this:

lib/init.php:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
```

and web/index.php:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../lib/init.php';

$app->get('/about', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('about.twig.html');
})
->bind('about');

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig.html');
})
->bind('homepage');

$app->run();
```

I am using MAMP to test on my local machine. When I visit localhost:8888/web it renders the index page fine, no problems, but visiting localhost:8888/web/about gives a 404 error.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The url is the part after `web/index.php`. So `/about` matches `web/index.php/about`.

Now you want to remove that `index.php` bit from the url. You can do this with HTACCESS, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424728/rewriterule-in-apache-with-symfony2-not-removing-app-php) to understand how.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was something to do with `.htaccess`, but it's been so long since I wrote any PHP.