# Remove web/app.php from the url in Symfony2 using .htaccess

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have some shared ftp location on which I am trying to use the Symfony2 Framework.

http://XYZ.com/ABC/Symfony

And All i have is the ftp details and the database.

Please help me to remove **web/app.php** form the url and that redirects to the main url.

Comment: What's wrong with [the default one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RewriteRule in Apache with Symfony2 not removing app.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424728/rewriterule-in-apache-with-symfony2-not-removing-app-php)

Comment: @Touki Want to remove web/app.php from the url and the default one only removes app.php still web is there and while opening the root url it shows error

Answer (score 5):

put this in your .htaccess file inside your web/ directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

taken from here - [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php)

Comment: Didn't worked. Still app.php is required and when I am trying
http://www.XYZ.com/Symfony it is showing error.

Comment: try to add `DocumentRoot /full/path/to/your/site/web` before `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

Comment: You might need to enable the rewrite module (sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart)