# Symfony - app.php required in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I recently deployed a symfony project and noticed that the only way I can currently access the project is using the following URL:

`http://domain.com/app.php/index`

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically get the `app.php` to be served without actually including it in the URL.

Something like:

`http://domain.com/index`

Not sure if `htaccess` is required for this or if this is something that can be accomplished directly using Symfony.

This is what my htaccess currently looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php/ [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

Comment: The above `.htaccess` which you reference is very close to the one which I use in my own Symfony projects and I don't have issues with serving URL's omitting the app.php as part of the URL pattern. I do, however have the re-write base commented out.

Comment: Thank Sean. The above `.htaccess` isnt working for me. I tried removing the re-write base all together, still no success. I get an internal server error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RewriteRule in Apache with Symfony2 not removing app.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424728/rewriterule-in-apache-with-symfony2-not-removing-app-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is (effectively) the `.htaccess` file which I use on several projects and sites using Symfony 2:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

I also have the following `vhost` entry for one of my Symfony projects under the apache server:

`<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot "<PATH_TO_PROJECT>/web"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "<PATH_TO_PROJECT>/app/logs/apache_error.log"
    ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] [pid %P] thread-%T %F: %E: [client %a] %M"
    <Directory "<PATH_TO_PROJECT>/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

The omission of the `DirectoryIndex app.php` index may be enough in the `.htaccess` file, so you could try that. Admittedly my knowledge of Apache configuration is weaker than I would like it to be, hopefully this helps, if not--hopefully some one out there can give you a better, stronger answer?

Best of luck!